# Converting NOT EXISTS to LEFT JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Currently I am trying to convert a SELECT statement that uses NOT EXISTS in the WHERE clause just like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    T1.TOneID
FROM
    TOne T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        1
    FROM 
    TTwo T2
    LEFT JOIN TThree T3 ON
    T3.TTwoId = T2.TTwoId
    WHERE
    T2.TOneId = T1.TOneId AND 
    (
    T2.Column IS NULL OR
    T3.Column IS NULL
    ) 
)
```

To another query using LEFT JOINS and a condition with WHERE X IS NULL on the Primary Keys of T2 and T3 instead. Unfortunately I don't get the same result in the new query as with the old query. Where am I going wrong? The reason why I try to do this is to optimize the performance of the query.

I tried the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
    T1.TOneID
FROM
    TOne T1
    LEFT JOIN TTwo T2 ON
      T2.TOneId = T1.TOneId AND
      T2.Column IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN TThree T3 ON
      T3.TTwoId = T2.TTwoId AND
      T3.Column IS NULL
WHERE
    T2.TTwoID IS NULL AND
    T3.TThreeID IS NULL
```

But this query gave me the wrong result compared to the old one. It produced rows that should not have benen there

Comment: Your query is saying it shouldn't find t2.Column or t3.Column as null. NOT EXISTS is just fine.

Comment: Why do you think converting NOT EXISTS to LEFT JOIN will improve the performance?

Comment: I'd suspect a `NOT EXISTS` to be more performant, as they can short circuit; a `LEFT JOIN` cannot.

Comment: This is a correlated subquery so left join might be faster?

Comment: @topsail - SQL Server treats `NOT EXISTS` as an anti semi join. Just another join type

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is a derived table and a `LEFT JOIN` to that. Impossible to test with no sample data and expected results mind:

```sql
SELECT T1.TOneID
FROM dbo.TOne T1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT T2.TOneId
                FROM dbo.TTwo T2
                     LEFT JOIN dbo.TThree T3 ON T3.TTwoId = T2.TTwoId
                WHERE T2.Column IS NULL OR T3.Column IS NULL) T ON T1.TOneId = T.TOneId
WHERE T.TOneId IS NULL;
```

Though I don't see why you feel a `LEFT JOIN` would be more performant than a `NOT EXISTS`; I doubt it will be.